# New iTunes Connect won't save after screenshots are added

Tags: app-store-connect

When I try to add screenshots to my app submission I get the following error when I try to save:

```
Your app information could not be saved. Try again. If the problem persists, contact us.
```

I have contacted them, I'm waiting on a response but I wanted to see if anyone has had luck here.

I have tried:

1. clearing cache
2. using Safari, Firefox, and Chrome to upload, no dice
3. Flattening the image
4. JPG and PNG formats with and without the transparency box checked
5. resaving in Preview
6. Downloading the previous screenshots and uploading again

If I try to upload an image that is the wrong size or has transparency I get an immediate error, this error tells me nothing and gives no further information.

** UPDATE 9/10 **
Apple customer service just contacted me asking for more information.  So either they're just giving me the default response or they don't have any idea what's happening. Sigh.

Comment: What is your product name?

Comment: Are you asking what's the app name?

Answer (score 3):

I fixed my error by opening chrome (after trying like 10 times in safari) and it just went through.

Comment: don't you just love the non-answer answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I spoke with Apple Support today about this error and they admitted it is an issue on their end.
There is no known workaround so far, and also no estimated time for a fix.
Too bad they can't just revert back to the previous version until they manage to QA appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

It is the problem related to web browser. To solve it, just ***clear cookies and cache*** of your current web browser or ***use a different web browser*** and you will be able to submit the build.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem as yours for all day long, and tried all you described...

I'm waiting for their response too

UPDATE:

Today, 09/09/14, the error changed in chrome. Now i get the following error:

`Failed to create a screenshot for Screenshots for 4-inch iPhone 5 and iPod touch (5th generation) Retina display`

In Safari i keep getting error:

`Your app information could not be saved. Try again. If the problem persists, contact us.`

UPDATE 2:

Clear cookies in safari made it present me the same error of chrome.

The 'inspect element' of both browsers now dont show a server (500) error anymore

UPDATE 3:

The error: `Your app information could not be saved. Try again. If the problem persists, contact us.` came back in both browsers.

Apple has answered my thread and asked for aditional information. Waiting on them

Comment: It sure has to do with the new iTC

Comment: I too have this issue.

Comment: I'm still getting this in Safari and Chrome... anyone else?

Answer (score 1):

When I update the version of my App, also encountered the same situation. After trying various methods, the solution is found.

1. upload a screenshot of the non-primary language,
   [image]
2. change the primary language,
   [image]
3. modify the non-primary language screenshot,
4. change back the primary language.

Yeah Succeed!!!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, also using Safari, and was able to fix it by opening up an alternative browser: Firefox *(I used firefox, and assume any alternate browser may fix the problem)*.

It appears something funky was going on with the HTTP request to save the image. I looked into the developer console and found the follwoing message.

> started to save version details

This message was followed by a javascript object with many properties including the image information, and a status labeled ***rejected***.

Not sure why this error is still being an issue after 11 months from the original post. It must be an intermittent browser error on a poor internet connection, and alternate browsers are more persistent in sending the image object.

Answer (score 0):

The error showed for me too after I added my app build. So I removed my app build and saved, then I added my screenshots and they were successfully uploaded.