# Itunes Connect unable to create screenshots once localization added

Tags: ios, localization, app-store-connect

the screenshots i've uploaded are fine when the only language is english. once i add localizations (chinese, russian, etc.) in itunes connect - none of the screenshots are accepted. i get the following error message; "Failed to create a screenshot for Screenshots for 4-inch iPhone 5 and iPod touch (5th generation) Retina display" (and the same for the rest of the screenshot sizes).

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a browser-related issue as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733107/new-itunes-connect-wont-save-after-screenshots-are-added) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25771894/error-uploading-screenshots-to-new-itunes-connect).
I recently faced the same problem in Firefox.
I managed to workaround the problem by using Internet Explorer for uploading screenshots.